# Show stopwatch in JTextPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextpane, stopwatch

I want to put my stopwatch to JTextPane in JPanel, but it doesn't appear :/ I don't know if I can put objetct from class `(extends JLabel)` in class  `(extends JPanel)`. Maybe, this is the reason.

My Stopwatch class:

```
    public class StopWatch extends JLabel implements ActionListener {

    private DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.0");
    private Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, this);
    private long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    public StopWatch() {
        this.setText(when());
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        setText(when());
    }

    public void start() {
        timer.start();
    }

    public void stop() {
        timer.stop();
    }

    private String when() {
        return df.format((System.currentTimeMillis() - now) / 1000d);
    }  
}
```

this is how I use it:

```
    public class Tlo extends JPanel {  
        ....       
        StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
        JTextPane time = new JTextPane();
        time.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 28));  
        time.setBounds(135,598,115,34);
        time.setBackground(new Color(182, 221, 232));
        time.setEditable(false);
        time.add(stopwatch);
        add(time);
        stopwatch.start(); 
        ...     
    }
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, while `JTextPane` inherits from the `Container` class, the [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add%28java.awt.Component%29) method does not add components to the `JTextComponent`'s document. Only these document components will be rendered.

Replace:

```
time.add(stopwatch);
```

with

```
time.insertComponent(stopwatch);
```